# Code for analyzing thresholds in R model output

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a textual classification problem that consists of two categories- zero an one. Up until now I tried solving it by creating a Document Term Matrix, and to run it through SVM (using RTextTools package). Here's a code snippet: (in R)

```
models <- train_models(container, algorithms=c("SVM"))
results <- classify_models(container, models)
analytics <- create_analytics(container, results)
View(summary(analytics))

>>ALGORITHM PERFORMANCE

>>SVM_PRECISION    SVM_RECALL    SVM_FSCORE 
>>         0.64          0.63          0.63
```

My questions are as follows:

1.Why are all the predicted values in the result matrix between 0.5-1? isn't it supposed to be 0-1?

2.Supposed we have theta as threshold to separate that all scores above it are of class 1, and the rest are 0. How can I analyze (in R) under which theta are these precision and recall values being calculated? How can I change this threshold to get different values?

3.How can I create in R two different thresholds values for each class (with what's left in between labeled as "unidentified")?

Comment: This is a question for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean by "1.Why are all the predicted values in the result matrix between 0.5-1? isn't it supposed to be 0-1?" ? Could you add those values to your question?